# Python's DRF, Field name " " is not valid for model

Tags: python, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have the following Model where I ask for the user's input.

```py
from django.db import models


# Create your models here.

class PostGDT1AndUAV(models.Model):


    latitude_gdt = models.FloatField(name='Latitude Of GDT 1',
                                     unique=True, max_length=255, blank=False,
                                     help_text="Enter the location's Latitude, first when extracting from Google Maps.",
                                     default=1)
    longitude_gdt = models.FloatField(name='Longitude Of GDT 1',
                                      unique=True, max_length=255, blank=False,
                                      help_text="Enter the location's Longitude, second when extracting from Google "
                                                "Maps.",
                                      default=1)

    latitude_uav = models.FloatField(name='Latitude Of UAV',
                                     unique=True, max_length=255, blank=False,
                                     help_text="Enter the location's Longitude, second when extracting from Google "
                                               "Maps.",
                                     default=1)
    longitude_uav = models.FloatField(name='Longitude Of UAV',
                                      unique=True, max_length=255, blank=False,
                                      help_text="Enter the location's Longitude, second when extracting from Google "
                                                "Maps.",
                                      default=1)
```

and it's serializer:

```py
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import PostGDT1AndUAV


class PostGDT1AndUAVSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = PostGDT1AndUAV
        fields = ('latitude_gdt', 'longitude_gdt', 'latitude_uav', 'longitude_uav')
```

When trying to print the instances of the object in the django shell I get the following error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Field name `latitude_gdt` is not valid for model `PostGDT1AndUAV`.
```

Also, I'm trying to make the fields in the model narrower, meaning, using one variable,

If I were to use regular python input I would do something like this:

```py
        gdt1_coord = input("Enter the first GDT's Lat/Lon coordinates")

        lat1, lon1 = gdt1_coord.split(',')

        lat1 = float(lat1)
        lon1 = float(lon1)

        gdt1 = [lat1, lon1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `name` kwarg is the field's name in the database, so it can not contain any spaces.
Try replacing it with `verbose_name`